# DevExpress VerticalGrid in unbound mode with MultiRecordLayout

Tags: devexpress-windows-ui

EDIT: As it turns out, the grid does not support unbound mode in MultiRecordView layout.

I will try to ask this question a different way since my last one was downvoted without comment, so I don't know what the downvoter was objecting to.

I've worked quite a lot with the DevExpress VerticalGrid in **unbound** mode in SingleRecordView. We use it in all of our desktop applications that involve lots of data-entry. All data-entry forms  are consistent in look-and-feel and so user training is minimal. I think it is a great control.

However, I don't understand how to use it in unbound mode in *MultiRecordView* layout. I cannot even figure out how to populate the unbound grid with the data for several records. In SingleRecord layout, I use the `RowsIterator` to move data from my data object in memory into the corresponding row/cell in the VerticalGrid's single record.

But in MultiRecordView layout, I can't figure out how to add the second record and the third record, etc etc, and position the current record pointer so that the `RowsIterator` is working with the rows of the correct record.

A small code snippet, showing how to move the current record pointer when adding the second and subsequent records in MultiRecordView, would be very helpful.

I've tried `AddNewRecord()` and setting the `FocusedRecord` but without success:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyTable.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       vGridControl1.AddNewRecord();                
       vGridControl1.FocusedRecord = i;
       vGridControl1.RowsIterator.DoOperation(new DataPuller(MyTable.Rows[i]));

   }
```

and here's a relevant snippet from my DataPuller object:

```
 public override void Execute(DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Rows.BaseRow brow)
{

 //<snip>

 if (brow is DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Rows.EditorRow)
  {
      string fieldname = brow.Properties.FieldName;
      if (table.Columns.Contains(fieldname))
         {
            brow.Properties.Value = (table[fieldname] == DBNull.Value) ? null : table[fieldname];
         }
   }

  //<snip>

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The vertical grid doesn't support unbound mode when in MultiRecordView layout.